# C++ vs C# operators precedence

Tags: c#, c++, operator-precedence

I have the same code on visual studio C++ and C# and each compiler has a **different output** although **both have the same precedence and associativity** table

On C++

```
    int i = 10;  
    int a = i++ + ++i + i--;  
    printf("a=%u\n",a);

    i = 10;
    a = i++ + i;
    printf("a=%u\n",a);

    int x=2,y=3;
    int z=((x++)*(x++))+((++y)*(++y));
    printf("x=%u , y=%u , z=%u \n",x,y,z);
```

the output is

```
a=33
a=20
x=4 , y=5 , z=29
```

On C#

```
            int i = 10;
            int a = i++ + ++i + i--;

            Console.WriteLine("a={0}",a);

            i = 10;
            a = i++ + i;

            Console.WriteLine("a={0}", a);

            int x = 2, y = 3;
            int z=((x++)*(x++))+((++y)*(++y));
            Console.WriteLine("x={0} , y={1} , z={2}",x,y,z);
```

the output is

```
a=34
a=21
x=4 , y=5 , z=26
```

In C# I found that the operation obey the precedence table that **post-increment has a higher precedence that pre-increment** and so it places the value then increment
I can't find any logical explanation for this . Could anyone explain this ?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in your C++ code because you are modifying `i` multiple times that are unsequenced. Anything could happen. I don't know how C# deals with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the code has undefined behaviour because side effect of the post-increment operator is not exactly sequenced relative to other operations.

In C# there is such notion as DAS (define assignment state); DAs before Expression `i` must be equal to DAS after Expression `i - 1`.

The order of calculation of expression `x++` or `x--` the following.

1. Value of `x` is calculated and saved.
2. The value is used to calculate `x++` or `x--` and also saved.
3. This saved result becomes the result of the operation.

So consider statement

```
int a = i++ + ++i + i--;
```

The first expression is `i++`. `i` is evaluated. Its value is `10`. It is saved as the value of the expression. Then operation `++` is applied. The result of operation is `11`. So the output DAS of `i` is equal to `11`. It is the input DAS for the next expression `++i`. Here `++i` is evaluated because there is pre-increment operator. The value is `12` and the output DAS of `i` is `12`. The order of evaluation of `i--` the same as `i++`. So we have

```
10 + 12 + 12 = 34
```

and the output DAS of `i` of the expression is `11`.

Maybe it is not very clear but the difference between C++ and C# is that C# made the process of evaluation of expressions more deterministic and clear, to avoid undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a case of precedence, but of operand evaluation order and sequencing of side-effects. In C++, evaluation order is unspecified, and you also get undefined behaviour from unsequenced modifications of a variable.

I've no idea whether or not C# specifies the behaviour of such insane code, but you shouldn't write such nonsense in any language.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698293/why-does-the-postincrement-has-a-higher-precedence-than-preincrement for more details